The notion of fundamental cogroup
I know there is a functor $\pi_1$ from the category of pointed topological spaces to the category of groups, sending each pointed topological space to its first fundamental group. I know that a group is just an $F$-algebra where $F$ is the endofunctor $F(X)=1+X+X^2$ on sets and each of the maps from $F(X)$ to $X$ makes a diagram commute, these diagrams corresponds to associativity, commutativity and unit element axioms. Therefore I can think of the codomain of $\pi_1$ as the category of those $F$-algebras which satisfy commutativity of certain diagrams. My question is, is there a functor whose domain is also topological spaces and the codomain is now the category of $F$-coalgebras satisfying coassociativity, cocommutativity and counital axioms (in other words, cogroups)? It would be interesting if the new functor behaved like $\pi_1$, for example being a homotopy invariant.

The only cogroup in sets is the empty set, so did you have in mind cogroups in another category? This isn't quite what you asked, but the $n$-sphere is a cogroup in $\mathbf{hTop}_*$, see here.

Oh, I didn't know empty set were the cogroup object in Set. I am just trying to construct a dual notion of fundamental group, maybe the coalgebraic approach is not the right one, at least for cogroups in Set.

This explains why I've never heard of a cogroup before. They don't exist!

@CheerfulParsnip they do exist, and are quite useful. But there are no interesting cogroups in set. However, as already pointed out, the n-sphere is a cogroup in the homotopy category of Top. This is what gives homotopy classes of maps out of the n-sphere a group structure, giving rise to the quite important higher homotopy groups

@IsAdisplayName I meant in Set, and almost wrote that in my comment, but somehow decided the sentence had more punch otherwise.
